# Icalendar DST issue

Tags: c#, icalendar

I am using iCal to generate outlook Recurring meetings invite from a portal. We are having different timezones on the portal. We convert all time to IST and perform the operation. and my code is as below. Problem i am facing is when a recurring request is generated for paris user, half of the invites shows correct time but left recurring invites which fall after DST(day light saving) shows 1 hour before time on calendar ideally it should be the same for them irrespective of DST. How to handle DST as there are multiple timezones which are having differnt DST for them. You can see in my code i have pass dtParentStime and dtParentEtime  the start and end time of parent invite in IST.

```
str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
str.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0");
str.AppendLine("METHOD:REQUEST");
str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VTIMEZONE");
str.AppendLine("TZID:Asia/Kolkata");
str.AppendLine("BEGIN:STANDARD");
str.AppendLine("TZOFFSETFROM:+0530");
str.AppendLine("TZOFFSETTO:+0530");            
str.AppendLine("TZNAME:IST");
str.AppendLine("END:STANDARD");
str.AppendLine("END:VTIMEZONE");
str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");
str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTART:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmss}", dtParentStime)); //dtParentStime is the the parent request's start time in IST
str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTAMP:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", DateTime.UtcNow));
str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTEND:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmss}", dtParentEtime)); //dtParentEtime is the parent request's end time in IST
str.AppendLine(string.Format("RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL={0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", utcEtime));

str.AppendLine("LOCATION:  ");            
str.AppendLine(string.Format("UID:{0}", meetingID));
str.AppendLine(string.Format("DESCRIPTION:{0}", msg.Body));
str.AppendLine(string.Format("X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:{0}", msg.Body));
str.AppendLine(string.Format("SUMMARY:{0}", msg.Subject));
str.AppendLine(string.Format("ORGANIZER:MAILTO:{0}", msg.From.Address));
str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VALARM");
str.AppendLine("TRIGGER:-PT15M");
str.AppendLine("ACTION:DISPLAY");
str.AppendLine("DESCRIPTION:Reminder");
str.AppendLine("END:VALARM");
str.AppendLine("END:VEVENT");
str.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR");
System.Net.Mime.ContentType ct = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/calendar");
ct.Parameters.Add("method", "REQUEST");
AlternateView avCal = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(str.ToString(), ct);
msg.AlternateViews.Add(avCal);            
sc.Send(msg);
```

I also tried passing UTC time for start and end time and removed vtimezone sections in above code. but the problem get worsed. as 10AM invite appearing at 8AM and after dst it appears at 7AM for CET timezone users.

Note:- if i use UTC time for start and end date with vtimezone section removed for single invite (non recurring invite) then calendar time is proper before DST and after DST as well. Is there something I am missing to add in RRULE?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to convert every date to UTC and format all with a "Z" at the end of the format string

```
str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTART:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", dtParentStime.ToUniversalTime()));
str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTEND:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", dtParentEtime.ToUniversalTime()));
```

or

```
str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTART:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", dtParentStime.UtcDateTime));
str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTEND:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", dtParentEtime.UtcDateTime));
```

And remove these lines

```
str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VTIMEZONE");
str.AppendLine("TZID:Asia/Kolkata");
str.AppendLine("BEGIN:STANDARD");
str.AppendLine("TZOFFSETFROM:+0530");
str.AppendLine("TZOFFSETTO:+0530");            
str.AppendLine("TZNAME:IST");
str.AppendLine("END:STANDARD");
str.AppendLine("END:VTIMEZONE");
```

I hope that helps you

Comment: Hi above solution didnt work, I applied utc and removed vtimezone lines. but that made the invite appear 2 hours before i.e. 10AM invite was appearing at 8AM and after DST it is appearing at 7AM for CET timezone.

Comment: For single invite (non recurring) your suggestion works fine. but for recurring meeting problem is same, is their some issue with RRULE ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply having the VTIMEZONE definition is not enough. You need to specify the TZID in the DTSTART and DTEND properties themselves:

```
str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTART;TZID=Asia/Kolkata:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmss}", dtParentStime));
str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTEND;TZID=Asia/Kolkata:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmss}", dtParentEtime));
```

Then if you want the event to remain at the same time of day for the CET users, you need to use a CET timezone instead of the Asia/Kolkata one. There is no way around it.

So you need to replace your VTIMEZONE component with something like:

```
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/Paris
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
DTSTART:19810329T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=-1SU
TZNAME:CEST
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
DTSTART:19961027T030000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=10;BYDAY=-1SU
TZNAME:CET
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
```

and reference the Europe/Paris TZID in your DTSTART/DTEND.
Of course the DTSTART/DTEND should have value corresponding to the CET time of day:

```
str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Paris:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmss}", dtParentStime));
str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTEND;TZID=Europe/Paris:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmss}", dtParentEtime));
```

Comment: Hi, it works the same with TZID and without it.  half of the invites shows correct time but left recurring invites which fall after DST(day light saving) shows 1 hour before time for CET users. As per the need time should change for IST user not for CET timezone users. but reverse is happening 1030AM CET calendar appear at 2PM at IST for all recurrence, but post DST for CET it is 930AM.

Comment: Did not notice that you wanted to have the events always in CET time. Edited my response accordingly.

Comment: Hi, on the portal we have a list of timezones and users select timezone as per their country. you mean i have to add TZID for every timezone that is selected?

Comment: Right. You need to add the one VTIMEZONE definition and TZID selected by the user in the invitation, if the recurring event is to be recurring at the same time of day for the user.